# How to copy only new files with same name but different data?

Tags: linux, bash

For context, I have a camera which takes pictures and gives them the file names `DSC_xxxx.JPG`. So, after a few hundred photos, I will export the photos to my laptop and then reformat the memory card. The problem is that this resets the counter for the camera so the next picture I take will be `DSC_0001.JPG`. This is a different picture from the `DSC_0001.JPG` that I have already exported on my laptop.

I didn't realize this. The next time I exported the photos on my laptop, I used the command `cp -R -u -p /camera/source /laptop/backup` and it overwrote all the old files. I thankfully have a backup, but now I am wondering how to proceed.

The memory card doesn't have a lot of memory so I can't not reformat the card every once in a while. Is there a command which only copies new files and maybe renames files with the same name but different data? Or should I approach this differently?

Comment: Delete the images on your memory card instead of formatting it?

Comment: Check the manual for your `cp`, there are options like `--backup` (backup existing destination files) and `--no-clobber` (do not overwrite existing destination files) that are supported in most versions.

Comment: `mkdir /laptop/backup/$(date --iso-8601)` and copy images to this new folder?